# Has anyone had any luck running Git on Windows using the "Smart HTTP" and Active Directory authentication?

Tags: windows, git, active-directory, smart-http

I have read that git now has a ["Smart HTTP" server](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html).  I am interested in using this with IIS on a Windows machine.  I would prefer to use the [msysgit](http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit) version of Git rather than the Cygwin.  Additionally, I would prefer to use Active Directory authentication rather than SSH.
  Has anyone had any luck with this.  I have read that the [git-http-backend](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html) cgi command "only works with Apache".  Having done a fair amount of Web development back when CGI scripts where still "cool" it is unclear to me why this would be an issue.  If someone can point me to a description of the problem I am willing to take a stab at resolving it.

Pat O

Comment: So I guess people are not using Git on Windows?  Or are people just not using Git?

Comment: Don't actually think this question deserved to be closed as too narrow.  Yes, perhaps the combination of Git on Windows, Smart HTTP and AD authentication seems narrow.  However I believe this question actually addresses the wider issue: How to use AD authentication with Git on Windows.